# jquery ajax request on android works only with async false

Tags: android, jquery

I have a jquery ajax request as below

```
$.ajax({
   url: "https://companydomain.com",
    username : "testuser",
    password : "testpassword",  
          async:false,            
        success: function(response, textStatus, jqXHR){
            // log a message to the console
            console.log("response :"+response);
    console.log("textStatus :"+textStatus);
    console.log("jqXHR :"+jqXHR);

        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
           console.log("jqXHR:"+jqXHR);
           console.log("textStatus :"+textStatus);
           console.log("Error"+errorThrown);
        },
        complete: function(){            
           console.log("complete");
        }
});
```

The issue is that this works on android emulator/device ONLY if "async:false" is set . It instantly fails when "async:true" is set. The above request works ok on iOS and on chrome desktop browser. Only android seems to be a problem . anyone knows what could be the probable cause ?

Android v4.0.X , 
Jquerymobile : jquery.mobile-1.2.0, 
phonegap : v2.1